# ScrollView cutting off part of the layout

Tags: android, layout, scrollview

I have a weird issue with a `ScrollView` in my layout, which is that it cuts off the bottom of the `TableLayout` within.
Here's what it looks like [when scrolling to the top.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htdXp.jpg)

The green background with the rounded corners should be the same for the bottom, i.e. it's really just a plain rectangle drawable with rounded corners. But when I try to scroll to the bottom, [here's what I see:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1YFx.jpg)

As you see, the bottom corners are invisible, I can't scroll any further. Now, I only see all lines of the Comments section because I manually added some `android:paddingBottom` to the `TableLayout` (see below), otherwise more would be cut off. And I just cannot figure out, what the problem is.
Can somebody tell me what I'm missing? Here is the XML layout. It is populated by a database query at runtime.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/table"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/some_shape"
        android:paddingBottom="40dp" >

        <TableRow android:layout_margin="20dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/code_label"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:text="Code:" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/code_field"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="test" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow android:layout_margin="20dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/name_label"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:text="Name:" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/name_field"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="test" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow android:layout_margin="20dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/pra_label"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:text="Type:" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/pra_field"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="test" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow android:layout_margin="20dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/day_label"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:text="Day:" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/day_field"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="test" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow android:layout_margin="20dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/room_label"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:text="Room:" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/room_field"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="test" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow android:layout_margin="20dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/time_label"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:text="Time:" />

            <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/time_field1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="test1" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/to" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/time_field2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="test2" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow android:layout_margin="20dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/comment_label"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:text="Comments:" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/comment_field"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="test" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: add fillviewport to your scrollview

Comment: @Mikel: Done. No effect.

Comment: yeah sorry my mistake, that works for the oposite, when you don't ocupy all screen and want the scroll to fill all.

Comment: Do you find solution? I have same problem.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's too late, but the answer is remove `android:layout_margin="30dp"` from TableLayout

Comment: Yes, all I had to do was remove the margin from the child object, THANK YOU!